# Video file types supported by PyQT Phonon

Tags: qt, pyqt, phonon

How can I find which video files are natively supported by QT's Phonon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supported MIME types vary depending on what backends are installed.  You can query for those by using availableMimeTypes() and isMimeTypeAvailable() from Phonon.BackendCapabilities .  See the [Phonon module reference](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/phonon-module.html).